# How to run a .jar inside browser?

Tags: php, html, browser, jar, debug-diagnostic-tool

I tried to execute a `.jar` using `HTML` or `PHP`.

In the first case I wrote the code below:

```html
<applet code=Diagnostica.class 
     archive="Diagnostica/Diagnostica.jar"
     width="120" height="120">
</applet>
```

This way doesn't work cause the file `Diagnostica.jar` need to contain an `applet` I suppose.

So I tried the second option in `PHP`:

```php
exec("java -jar Diagnostica/Diagnostica.jar");
```

This way it works. `Diagnostica.jar` starts outside the browser, but I want to start it inside the browser.

How can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that file does not contain an Applet, I do not think you will be able to start it in the browser (have a look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/run.html)).

Executing it via `exec` should work like executing it via the command line - but as you already noticed, it will be run on the server - not the client.

If it should run on the client, you'll either have to use a Java Applet or let the user download the jar-executable and execute it via command line etc.